Can't populate column using if statement comparing 2 columns running through 2 loops
New to Google apps script and sheets script*
I have 3 columns with data:

The first is a number representation of the second column which contains names both 52631 rows long,
The third is like a list of names that I need to compare to the second one, if both are the same I need to put that number from the same row in a new column 4. Column 3 is 52631 rows long.

I'm fixing and learning here and there for a few hours but can't get this to work.
Example:



number
unique-name
names
result (that I need to do)




1
hi
hello
2


2
hello
good night



3
morning
afternoon



4
good day
night





hi
1




hello
2




morning
3



Here is what I got until now:
function addLogNumber() {

  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
  
  for (var i = 1; i <= 52631; i++) {//loop for third column

    for (var j = 1; j <= 3209; j++) {//loop for second column

      var tabelaSis = range.getCell(3,i).getValue();//third column
      var nomeLog = range.getCell(2,j).getValue();//second column
      var codLog = range.getCell(1,j).getValue();//first column
      
        if(tabelaSis==nomeLog){
          range.getCell(i,4).setValue(codLog);
          break;
        }
    }
  }
}


Comparing 2 Cells using a Loop
I modified and removed some of your code, the .getActiveRange(); will return the position of the active cell and also I remove the other for loop. If the Second Column match on the Third Column the Fourth Column will be inputted the number of First Column, Based on my understanding of your problem this is the result.
Sample Output:

Sample Code:
function addLogNumber() {

  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  const unique = range.getRange(2,2,range.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const name = range.getRange(2,3,range.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().filter(n => n);

  for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
    unique.includes(name[i]) ? range.getRange(i + 2, 4).setValue(unique.indexOf(name[i]) + 1) : null;
  }
}

Reference:

For Loop

If Statment

JavaScript String Reference

JavaScript Array Reference



This is a plain lookup. You can use XLOOKUP like,
=ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP(C2:C,B2:B,A2:A,))

in D2.
